# How to install latest nodejs (13) on OpenSUSE?

Tags: software-installation, opensuse, node.js

It seems that the most recent version in standard package managers is nodejs10. Is there any options to install nodejs13 or at least 12, or nvm?

None of instructions I found on the Internet worked for me, unfortunately.

My version is openSUSE Leap 15.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here how I done it - the only option that seemed doable was building that from source, so according to https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-nodejs-on-supported-platforms

1. download source code from https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
2. unpack
3. check that all build tools are in place: `$ sudo zypper install python gcc-c++ make`
4. `$ ./configure`
5. `$ make -j4`
6. build some docs if you want it: `$ make doc`
7. `$ sudo make install`

That's it